# How to sort object by Date in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting, sort-object

**Want to sort this object by date in dart**
[image]

## I try use build in method .sort but it's not correct

Comment: can you share the list of objects in text form

Comment: The elements in the image appear to be in chronological order.  Please describe your specific problem and exactly what you did. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to convert date string into `Datetime`.

To sort in ascending order you can use:

```js
list_name.sort((a, b) => (DateFormat('yyyy-MMM').parse(a).compareTo(DateFormat('yyyy-MMM').parse(b))));
```

To sort in descending order use `-` in this:

```js
l.sort((a, b) => -(DateFormat('yyyy-MMM').parse(a).compareTo(DateFormat('yyyy-MMM').parse(b))));
```